# What are the other compatible batteries for acer travelmale P253-M?

Tags: battery, acer-travelmate

I've a acer travelmate (ntebook) P253-M, whose battery I'm trying to replace. My question is: is there any other batteries that could be used instead of the exact model? For example, do I have to use the battery with the exact specification(s). Will for example an acer aspire do, or, saw will a lenovo do (I don't think, but still checking)? The reason I'm asking is that I can't find the same model myself anywhere online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just head to a (computer) battery supply site and look it up by the product.

For example [here's what Battery Depot (.com) has](http://www.battdepot.com/us/model/notebook+battery/acer/travelmate+p253-m.aspx) to say about what is available for your Acer:

> LAC215C
>
> Replacement Notebook Battery for Acer TravelMate P253-M
>   10.8 Volt Li-ion Laptop Battery (4200mAh )
>
> LAC215X
>
> Replacement Notebook Battery for Acer TravelMate P253-M
>   10.8 Volt Li-ion Laptop Battery (6600mAh / 71Wh)
>
> LAC215-AP
>
> Replacement Notebook Battery for Acer TravelMate P253-M
>   10.8 Volt Li-ion Advanced Pro Series Laptop Battery (4400mAh / 48Wh)
>
> LAC215-GS
>
> Replacement Notebook Battery for Acer TravelMate P253-M
>   10.8 Volt Li-imide Green Series Laptop Battery (4800mAh / 52Wh)